# Jquery addOption Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    val1 = "1";
    text1 = "the text";
    var myOptions = {
        val1 : text1
    }

 $("#map_element_map_element_folder_id").addOption(myOptions, true);
```

i have this script.
but when i run it
option which added to select box is

text = "the text"  <- this one is correct

value = 'val1' <- its not supposed to be like this, it supposed fill with "1", because i declare val1 = "1" in top of script

anyone have idea what happen in here?

Comment: you are assigning `1` to `val1` and then over-writting its value with `the text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are defining an object, you may expect var1 to set the key as the value you defined for the var1 variable. However to do dynamic object key assignment, you have to use the bracket style:

```
var myOptions = {};
myOptions[var1] = text1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myOptions = {
        val1: val1,
        text1:text1
    };
```